# Await result of API call and update list component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling a REST API and return chat rooms. Those get returned fine, as I can see in the payload of the object via the console.

Now I want to display this in a list.

I was able to display a list and download the chat rooms, but not combine both. This is what I did:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function ChatRoomList({param1}) {
  var x = getChatRoom(param1)
  console.log(x)

    return  (
        <div>
             <li>{param1}</li>
             <li> asd  </li>
             <li> asd  </li>
        </div>
    );
  }


async function getChatRoom(status) {

    // status could be either 'open' or 'room'
    var dict = { 
        chatType: status,
        };

    var adminChats = await callKumulosAPIFunction(dict, 'getAdminChat')
    return adminChats
}
```

Now I did try to simply `await` the first `getChatRoom(param1)` call. But I can only await inside an async function. I then tried to add the async keyword to the export function, but this would crash the whole app.

How would the workflow be here? And how would I map the result from getChatRoom onto a listview?

The result of the adminChats (console.log(adminChats)):

[image]

Comment: A React component can't be an `async` function. Read up on _hooks_ - `useState` and `useEffect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use useEffect hook to get remote data:

```
export default function ChatRoomList({param1}) {

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    (async () => {
        var x = await getChatRoom(param1)
        console.log(x)
    })()
  },[])  

    return  (
        <div>
             <li>{param1}</li>
             <li> asd  </li>
             <li> asd  </li>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

If the data returned from getChatRoom is an array and you want to show it, you need to save the response in a state, or the component will not re-render:

```
export default function ChatRoomList({param1}) {
  const [chatRooms, setChatRooms] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    (async () => {
        var x = await getChatRoom(param1)
        setChatRooms(x)
    })()
  },[])  

    return  (
        <div>
             <li>{param1}</li>
             {chatRooms.map((chatRoom , index) => {
                return <li key={index}>{JSON.stringify(chatRoom)}</li>
             })}
        </div>
    );
  }

async function getChatRoom(status) {

    // status could be either 'open' or 'room'
    var dict = { 
        chatType: status,
        };

    var adminChats = await callKumulosAPIFunction(dict, 'getAdminChat')
    return adminChats.payload
}
```

I suggest you to read the documentation about React hooks and lifecycle management:

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html
2. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Hello and thank you for the help. I will definately read into this. For now, I am getting the error "chatRooms.map is not a function". I believe this is because the result of var x is not directly an array but x.payload would be. But I fail to understand how setChtRooms(x) works when I only see this word appear in the const. Can you explain this a little for me? that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the error is because x is not an array. If you post the response I can help you, or try to replace setChatRooms(x) with setChatRooms(x.payload). What do you mean for "I only see this word appear in the const"?

Comment: thank you again, i edited my question with the result of the api call. I tried x.payload but still it fails. Can you look into this again? :)

Comment: I updated the answer. If you are still getting  "chatRooms.map is not a function" is because getChatRoom is not returning an array, in this case add a console.log(x) before setChatRooms

Comment: FYI, when trying setChatRooms(x.payload) I am getting (shortend):  Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userID1, userID2, chatIDFromTableChats, ..., users, status}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: I edited the answer and added JSON.stringify to let you see what is inside the element. 
The api response is an array of objects. You need to select which field of the object to show and replace for example {chatRoom} with {chatRoom.userID1}

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `useEffect` hook to call the API.
Read more about [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```
import * as React from 'react';

     function getChatRoom(status) {
        const [chats, setChats] = React.useState([]);
    
        const getChart = async (status) => {
            // status could be either 'open' or 'room'
            const  dict = { 
            chatType: status,
            };
    
            const adminChats = await callKumulosAPIFunction(dict, 'getAdminChat');
            setChats(adminChats);
        };
    
        React.useEffect(() => {
            getChart(status)
        }, [status])
    
    
        return { chats };
    };
    
    export default function ChatRoomList({param1}) {
      const { chats } = getChatRoom(param1)
      console.log(chats)
    
        return  (
            <div>
                 <li>{param1}</li>
                 {chats?.map((chatRoom , index) => {
                   return <li key={index}>{JSON.stringify(chatRoom)}</li>
                 })}
            </div>
        );
      }
```

Dependencies argument of `useEffect` is `useEffect(callback, dependencies)`

Let's explore side effects and runs:

**Not provided: the side-effect runs after every rendering.**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs after EVERY rendering
  });  
}
```

**An empty array []: the side-effect runs once after the initial rendering.**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
  }, []);
}
```

**Has props or state values `[prop1, prop2, ..., state1, state2]`: the side-effect runs only when any dependency value changes.**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent({ prop }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
    // and after every rendering ONLY IF `prop` or `state` changes
  }, [prop, state]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I am getting: React Hook "React.useState" is called in function "getChatRoom" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter 

when trying your code

Comment: It's a better approach to you can convert in custom hook and used it in your app.

Comment: Not to be rude, @innom, but if you read that error, it tells you exactly what's wrong with your code.